# wrong content elements in translation of tx_news

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

TYPO3 8.7, tx_news 7.2 or 7.3.1.

I use tx_news with attached content elements. In default language all work fine, but when i translate the news article i get a single wrong content element in the list of translated content elements, always on first place.

In steps: 
- translating news article
- alle depending content elements are correctly translated
- on first place there is a foreign - translated - content element which does not belong to the news but to a total different page in the tree. 
- when i translate the next news article the same content element ist now connected to the new translation - and so on. 
- when i click on "Synchronize with default language" the wrong content element is deleted! (Which is wrong and should not happen, of course!)

In the database the wrong content element gets for every translation a new entry in the field "tx_news_related_news. It shuffles from news article to news article ... In the end i get an element which is connected with the news entry which was translated last.

When i delete this content element (or click on "Synchronize with default language" which results in the same) a new false content element is used and begin to shuffle from article to article.

Any ideas what`s going on? Or how to fix it?

Peter